# How to combine multiple OpenTelemetry traces into one original trace?

Tags: java, event-handling, jaeger, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry

Below is a rough sketch of how our SpringBoot microservices communicate with a Remote Blockchain app, which triggers events based on the requests send to it. The blockchain can generate **multiple events for a single request**, and this triggers multiple Traces to be generated on the auto-instrumented event-listening service "**C**"

Please suggest how can we combine these multiple traces on the receiving side with the original trace that was generated at the start of the flow. A few points about our service that might give better clarity :

1. At the start of the flow, we are generating a **unique msg-id** that is used to correlate the logs, and it flows through all the microservices.
2. Perhaps we serialize the context in service "**B**", just before hitting the blockchain, and then when service "**C**" receives events from the blockchain, we use the msg-id to fetch the related span context from DB/File and create a child span out of that? will that "unite" the traces?

[image]

Comment: Hello, currently facing the same issue. Did you come up with any solution?

Comment: yes, you need to have spanbuilder create a new spans with the original TraceId.

Comment: @Somjit can you please post here the correct answer and what did you end up doing? (not a reply but an actual answer). thanks